# Converting series from pandas to pyspark: need to use "groupby" and "size", but pyspark yields error

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, group-by, series

I am converting some code from Pandas to pyspark. In pandas, lets imagine I have the following mock dataframe, df:

[image]

And in pandas, I define a certain variable the following way:

```
value = df.groupby(["Age", "Siblings"]).size()
```

And the output is a series as follows:

[image]

However, when trying to covert this to pyspark, an error comes up: `AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'size'`. Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of `size` in `pyspark` is [`count`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.count):

```
df.groupby(["Age", "Siblings"]).count()
```

Comment: `count` returns the number of rows: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.count

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `agg` method, which is more flexible as it allows you to set column alias or add other types of aggregations:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.groupby('Age', 'Siblings').agg(F.count('*').alias('count'))
```