# Dividing dataframes in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, divide

Following up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65707148/converting-series-from-pandas-to-pyspark-need-to-use-groupby-and-size-but) question and dataframes, I am trying to convert this

[image]

Into this (I know it looks the same, but refer to the next code line to see the difference):

[image]

In pandas, I used the line code `teste_2 = (value/value.groupby(level=0).sum())` and in pyspark I tried several solutions; the first one was:

```
 df_2 = (df/df.groupby(["age"]).sum())
```

However, I am getting the following error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'DataFrame' and 'DataFrame'`

The second one was:

```
df_2 = (df.filter(col('Siblings'))/gr.groupby(col('Age')).sum())
```

But it's still not working. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Could you show sample dataframe and desired output?

Comment: Yes, sorry, will edit @mck

Comment: @mck Edited! I think it's more understandable now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I've understood the question correctly. It seems you want to divide the count by the sum of count for each age group.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.groupBy('age', 'siblings').count().withColumn(
    'count',
    F.col('count') / F.sum('count').over(Window.partitionBy('age'))
)

df2.show()
+---+--------+-----+
|age|siblings|count|
+---+--------+-----+
| 15|       0|  1.0|
| 10|       3|  1.0|
| 14|       1|  1.0|
+---+--------+-----+
```