# Converting dataframe to dictionary in pyspark without using pandas

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Following up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65716510/dividing-dataframes-in-pyspark/65717214#65717214) question and dataframes, I am trying to convert a dataframe into a dictionary. In pandas I was using this:

```
dictionary = df_2.unstack().to_dict(orient='index')
```

However, I need to convert this code to pyspark. Can anyone help me with this? As I understand from previous questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41206255/convert-pyspark-sql-dataframe-dataframe-type-dataframe-to-dictionary) I would indeed need to use pandas, but the dataframe is way too big for me to be able to do this. How can I solve this?

EDIT:

I have now tried the following approach:

```
dictionary_list = map(lambda row: row.asDict(), df_2.collect())
dictionary  = {age['age']: age for age in dictionary_list}
```

([reference](https://pythonpedia.com/en/knowledge-base/41206255/convert-pyspark-sql-dataframe-dataframe-type-dataframe-to-dictionary)) but it is not yielding what it is supposed to.

In pandas, what I was obtaining was the following:

[image]

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: @mck I added a printscreen in the question

Comment: @mck the original code I had in pandas for the whole process was this: dictionary = (value/value.groupby(level=0).sum()).unstack().to_dict(orient='index'), refering to the dataframe in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65707148/converting-series-from-pandas-to-pyspark-need-to-use-groupby-and-size-but

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df2` is the dataframe from the previous post. You can do a pivot first, and then convert to dictionary as described in your linked post.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df3 = df2.groupBy('age').pivot('siblings').agg(F.first('count'))
list_persons = [row.asDict() for row in df3.collect()]
dict_persons = {person['age']: person for person in list_persons}

{15: {'age': 15, '0': 1.0, '1': None, '3': None}, 10: {'age': 10, '0': None, '1': None, '3': 1.0}, 14: {'age': 14, '0': None, '1': 1.0, '3': None}}
```

Or another way:

```
df4 = df3.fillna(float('nan')).groupBy().pivot('age').agg(F.first(F.struct(*df3.columns[1:])))
result_dict = eval(df4.select(F.to_json(F.struct(*df4.columns))).head()[0])

{'10': {'0': 'NaN', '1': 'NaN', '3': 1.0}, '14': {'0': 'NaN', '1': 1.0, '3': 'NaN'}, '15': {'0': 1.0, '1': 'NaN', '3': 'NaN'}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working :( "TypeError: 'map' object is not callable"

Comment: I am using the edited version, unfortunately the error it's still there for me :(

Comment: @Johanna I removed that annoying function, could you please try again?